# t-test on regression slopes using python

Tags: regression, time-series, t-test, python

As an exercise, I am calculating an OLS regression on time series data. I would like to compare the slope from the regression (trend) to a value I specify. For example, if I take a time series of temperature, I would like to compare the trend of this data, to say the global average temperature trend. I am a bit new to stats, so sorry if these answers are obvious.

I currently am estimating the regression with the 'statsmodels' package, I am not sure how to use statsmodels or scipy.stats to do this calculation. Below is what I have so far, but I believe this assumes a null of zero.

```
model = sm.OLS(np.arange(0,len(temp.index)),np.asarray(temp.values))
results = model.fit()
slope = results.params[0]
p_value = stats.t.sf(results.tvalues[0], results.df_resid)
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.t_test.html

Answer (score 1):

This is how to calculate this manually, I wish python had an easier way to replace the null hypothesis in the t-test functions.

```
t_value = ((slope - (null_hypothesis))/results.bse) #bse = standard error
p_value = stats.t.sf(t_value, results.df_resid) #calculate p-value from t-statistic lookup tables
```